# stylesheet does not work after publishing

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

```
<link type ="text/css" href="../../Content/jquery.treeview.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<link type ="text/css" href="../../Content/screen.css" rel="Stylesheet" />

<script src="/../../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/../../js/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/../../js/jquery.treeview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i am working with mvc. i have these css and js links in my view. it works perfectly when i work on localhost. but after publishing, it seems like these css or js files does not work. i checked authorization settings of these files and there is nothing wrong.

Comment: `/../../` I'm pretty much sure that this path will not be resolved because front `/` points to webserver root.

Comment: Check the browser console for 404 errors.

Comment: yes i was the problem. when o dragged and dropped the css file, link appears like `/../../` . i changed it to `../` and it works! thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use asp.net MVC functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<link type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/content/jquery.treeview.css")" rel="Stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving path like this. i think you should provide the `full path`. After giving the full path, it will work everywhere.

```
<link type ="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/Content/jquery.treeview.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<link type ="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/Content/screen.css" rel="Stylesheet" />

<script src="http://www.domain.com/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.domain.com/js/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.domain.com/js/jquery.treeview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Why should you use absolute paths? "After giving the full path, it will work everywhere." Especially this is not true!

Comment: @LinusCaldwell Full path give us the freedom to include the file everywhere on the domain.

Comment: With starting the path with `/` you get the same advantage, but be independent from domains.

Comment: Well i always use full path, and always recommend. It depends from person to person that what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the URL where you are having the problem? It sounds like an issue with your relative
paths.

Here is what you can do:

1. Open up the site in Chrome
2. View page source
3. Up in the header, right click on the link to your CSS file and select Open Link in New Window

My guess is that you will get a Not Found error. Look at the URL to the non-existent CSS file
and see if it matches up to where you *think* it is.

Best,

Cynthia

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to insert URLs of contents in your MVC web application is by using Url helper.

*E.g.*

Css:

```
<link type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.treeview.css")" rel="Stylesheet" />
```

Scripts:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```